# Is there a way to simplify/consolidate this send function

Tags: c++

Is there a way to simplify/consolidate this send function for example:

```
int __fastcall HSend(void* _this, void* unknown,  BYTE* buffer, int len) {
    if (len > 0)
    {
        std::cout << std::hex << "[Packet]" << std::endl;
        std::stringstream EncrpytedPacket;
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            EncrpytedPacket << std::hex << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(2) << (unsigned int)(unsigned char)buffer[i];
        }
        std::cout << "[Send][" << EncrpytedPacket.str() << "]" << std::endl;

    }
    return oSend(_this, buffer, len);

}
```

Comment: What don't you like about the code you provided in your example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `endl`.  Just output `\n` to write a newline character.  It is rather slow, and output to console is "unit buffered" anyway.

Doing all the iostream mode changes, fill, width, etc. for every single byte in a loop is slow.  Which of those are remembered between calls anyway?  Or, use an efficient function to convert a bunch of bytes to hex in one call.

```
(unsigned int)(unsigned char)buffer[i]
```

Why are you stacking casts?